# Ubuntu Freezes unpredictably

Tags: drivers, freeze, hardware

Ubuntu freezes without any discernible pattern. I could have few apps open or many. It freezes in the middle of a video or when the computer is not in use.

The frequency of the freeze is not regular either. It can happen within minutes of logging on or after hours of work. The only pattern I see is that it happens at least once per hour while I'm working, and happens rarely while idle.

I've been using Ubuntu this way for several months now.

I've tried keyboard shortcuts but they won't work because the computer becomes completely unresponsive.

Are there log files containing recovery info that I could look at that might give some hint regarding these crashes?

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- I'm running ubuntu on a Dell Inspiron
  Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 35)

---

@heynnema

```
~$ free -h
      total   used   free   shared   buff/cache   available
Mem:  7.7Gi   1.2Gi  3.9Gi  175Mi    2.6Gi        6.0Gi
Swap: 2.0Gi   0B     2.0Gi

~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60

~$ swapon -s
Filename     TypeSize    Size       Used  Priority
/swapfile    file        2097148    0     -2
```

---

The system often freezes silently. i.e. I don't hear a lot of disk activity. I found this suspicious message at the tail end of /var/log/syslog right after a freeze occurance...

Aug 20 16:03:27 tracker-miner-f[1468]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in array-update: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

---

I'm not using wayland...

```
~$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION
ubuntu
```

UPDATE...
I've done further research and have concluded the problem is most likely being caused by incompatible hardware or mismatched driver that only gets installed when ubuntu is installed. Can anyone please help me to effectively isolate the problem driver?

The reasons for my conclusion:

- I have re-installed Ubuntu 20.04 (focal fossa) on an eternal SSD and the system still DOES freeze.
- I re-installed the original Windows 10 and the system DOES NOT freeze.
- I'm now using the LiveCD and the so far the system DOES NOT freeze.

Isolating the problem would allow me to report to developers and would likely help Ubuntu to become a more robust OS. I may be interested in helping by writing drivers for problem hardware.

To help me continue testing, it would be nice to have some way of using the LiveCD daily without having to reconfigure my preferences every time I reboot. Is there a way to write a script to add a user who's home directory resides on a flash drive?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: You may find some information in `/var/log/syslog` that points to an issue. Generally system freezes are the result of overheating or running out of memory.

Comment: Are you using Wayland?,  It has issues with a lot of video drivers..  Try switching to standard xorg see if it improves things